# get root element on selector

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get the root element on a selector?

It came to my attention that a selector such as

```
document.getElementById("chk").checked
```

gets the property for a checkbox - and if it changes, it reflects that value.

For jQuery 1.9.1

```
$("#chk").checked
```

no longer returns the property whereas

```
$("#chk").prop('checked');
```

does return the property.

**My question is, is there a way, from a selector jQuery object such as $('#chck') to get the base element so that a .checked would work?**

Note that I filed a jQuery bug on the checkbox property issue, as that seems like it should work but that is not my question specifically.

Comment: `$("#chk").checked` will actually yield `undefined` (I think that's always been the case). Maybe you're looking for `$("#chk")[0].checked`?

Comment: `$("#chk")` is always a jQuery object, which does NOT have a `.checked` property, while `document.getElementById("chk")` is always a DOM element, which does. Your bug report wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#chk")[0].checked
$("#chk").get(0).checked
```

etc ...

This is the intended funcionality, `.checked` only works on native DOM elements, while `prop()` is a jQuery method.